# Oracle. Calculate sum of one column in subgroup and save the others column in query result

Tags: oracle11g, group-by

I have table1 like this. 

`id | name |   sum1  | sum2 | bonus
———|——————|—————————|——————|——————
9  |   X  | 225     | 0,68 |     3
10 |   X  | 30      | 0,85 |     3
11 |   X  | 3384,73 | 0,8  |     3
15 |   Y  | 2800    | 2    |     3
16 |   Y  | 500     | 0    |     0
17 |   Y  | 2077,49 | 0,8  |     3
18 |   Y  | 26736,96| 0,7  |     8
19 |   Z  | 209,9   | 1,5  |     3
20 |   Z  | 700     | 1    |     3
21 |   Z  | 6550    | 0    |     0`

I want sum bonus column for each of "name" subgroup and get in result query table2

`id      | name |   sum1  | sum2 | bonus
————————|——————| ————————|——————|——————
9       |   X  | 225     | 0,68 |     3
10      |   X  | 30      | 0,85 |     3
11      |   X  | 3384,73 | 0,8  |     3
totalX  | null |  null   | null |     9
15      |   Y  | 2800    | 2    |     3
16      |   Y  | 500     | 0    |     0
17      |   Y  | 2077,49 | 0,8  |     3
18      |   Y  | 26736,96| 0,7  |     8
totalY  | null |  null   | null |    14
19      |   Z  | 209,9   | 1,5  |     3
20      |   Z  | 700     | 1    |     3
21      |   Z  | 6550    | 0    |     0
totalZ  | null |  null   | null |     6`

I did try "over partition by"

```sql
SELECT table1.*, sum(bonus)  over (PARTITION by name) as bonus_total FROM table1
```

It got me an extra column with bonus sum for each subgroup but this is not exactly what I want to get

`id      | name |   sum1  | sum2 | bonus| bonus_total
————————|——————| ————————|——————|——————|————————————
9       |   X  | 225     | 0,68 |     3|           9
10      |   X  | 30      | 0,85 |     3|           9
11      |   X  | 3384,73 | 0,8  |     3|           9
15      |   Y  | 2800    | 2    |     3|          14
16      |   Y  | 500     | 0    |     0|          14
17      |   Y  | 2077,49 | 0,8  |     3|          14
18      |   Y  | 26736,96| 0,7  |     8|          14
19      |   Z  | 209,9   | 1,5  |     3|           6
20      |   Z  | 700     | 1    |     3|           6
21      |   Z  | 6550    | 0    |     0|           6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by doing a partial group by rollup plus some conditional clauses:

```
with table1 as (select 9 id, 'X' name, 225 sum1, 0.68 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 10 id, 'X' name, 30 sum1, 0.85 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 11 id, 'X' name, 3384.73 sum1, 0.8 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 15 id, 'Y' name, 2800 sum1, 2 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 16 id, 'Y' name, 500 sum1, 0 sum2, 0 bonus from dual union all
                select 17 id, 'Y' name, 2077.49 sum1, 0.8 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 18 id, 'Y' name, 26736.96 sum1, 0.7 sum2, 8 bonus from dual union all
                select 19 id, 'Z' name, 209.9 sum1, 1.5 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 20 id, 'Z' name, 700 sum1, 1 sum2, 3 bonus from dual union all
                select 21 id, 'Z' name, 6550 sum1, 0 sum2, 0 bonus from dual)
select   case when id is null then 'total'||name else to_char(id) end id,
         case when id is not null then name end name,
         case when id is not null then sum(sum1) end sum1,
         case when id is not null then sum(sum2) end sum2,
         sum(bonus) bonus
from     table1 t1
group by name, rollup (id)
order by t1.name, t1.id;

ID       NAME       SUM1       SUM2      BONUS
-------- ---- ---------- ---------- ----------
9        X           225        .68          3
10       X            30        .85          3
11       X       3384.73         .8          3
totalX                                       9
15       Y          2800          2          3
16       Y           500          0          0
17       Y       2077.49         .8          3
18       Y      26736.96         .7          8
totalY                                      14
19       Z         209.9        1.5          3
20       Z           700          1          3
21       Z          6550          0          0
totalZ                                       6
```

The case statements are required purely to get the formatting you required. I had to include sums around the sum1 and sum2 columns in order to get them to appear in the results as you wanted - we turn them into nulls for the output.

Also, I am assuming that the id column is set to disallow null values.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It's exactly what I want to get.

Comment: if I add to table some varchar column with random values what should I do to be sure that query still work properly?
For now I'm using 'listagg' function but don't know if it's great solution?
`case when id is not null then listagg(str,'') within group(order by id) end str`
Code: http://pastebin.com/PSPfxtqq

Comment: This should really be a new question (although you can link back to this one), complete with the new input data (preferably in the same sort of format I used), the expected output and what you have tried so far.